# Rotation doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, xna, rotation

I think I do not have the `Rotation` and `Origin` parameters correct.

First off, I am programming a little Role-Playing-Game with XNA and I want to rotate a sprite depending on the direction it looks to. I have the right Rotation and everything for sure, but I think I'm probably drawing it the wrong way.

Why doesn't this work?

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position, null, Color.White, Rotation, new Vector2(Texture.Width/2, Texture.Height/2), 1, SpriteEffects.None,  1);
```

I thought you calculate the Origin with `Texture.Width / 2` and `Height / 2`?

Comment: Could you explain exactly what is happening, that you don't want to happen?

Comment: Oups sorry, totally forgot ;)
The texture is getting drawed ca 25 Pixel (that's Texture.Width/2, by the way) left from the normal Position and 25 Pixel above... @Nahuel I.

Comment: What do you mean "Doesn't work"? And have you tried Vector.Zero for the origin?

Comment: That is the correct way for calculating origin, what do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: I want to rotate it around the center @Pierre-Luc Pineault
And it doesn't really doesn't work, but it works the wrong way:
Instead of rotating the sprite around the Middle of the Texture, it is drawing the texture itself half a tile (50x50) too much left and too high. THERE it is rotating correctly, but why doesn't it draw the texture to it's right position??

Comment: Yes, but what is the issue? What is happening? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: It sounds like the sprite is rotating by taking the rotation point as Vector2.Zero instead of the middle of the sprite, is that right? I had that problem once, but need to check how I solved it... @Terrenay

Comment: http://de.tinypic.com/r/t9ia8x/8 @Cyral

Comment: Are you talking about the position? In that case the Position needs to be `Position - new Vector2(Texture.Width / 2, Texture.Height / 2)`

Comment: @Cyral I'll try it out tomorrow, but wouldn't it be Position + etc.?
Because - would move it even further away from where it have to be, or am I wrong? So or so, good night ^^

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using your origin, your position that you will see in the game will be slightly higher and to the left than without using a center origin, because you are subtracting the origin from the position when you rotate it.

Try storing your origin in a `Vector2` and adding it to your position when you draw your object.

```
Vector2 Origin = Vector2(Texture.Width/2, Texture.Height/2);
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position + Origin, null, Color.White, Rotation, Origin, 1, SpriteEffects.None,  1);
```